# CSS - buttons are unclickable from time to time?

Tags: css, button, hover, margin

I have multiple anchor elements. Once in a while clicking on them does nothing, all the CSS animations work but the links are not opening any pages / triggering any actions. I have to move cursor a little and then click again.

I'm sure it's a CSS issue, but I can't find anything wrong in my CSS. I think the problem may lie in margins (4px bottom margin BUT 4px top margin on :active) but I've seen this on many websites and the buttons were working just fine...

Here are the buttons. Click on them, around one of 20 clicks doesn't work (sometimes it happens with the very first click though):

http://jsfiddle.net/4nz4v/ (notice how buttons are not getting .active class after clicks, tested it in both latest Opera and Chrome)

Here's the CSS:

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #000;
    background: #aaa;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0.6em 1.2em;
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
    text-decoration: none;  
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.button:active {
    margin: 4px 0 0 0;
}

.active {
    background: #fff;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #000;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: They work fine for me.

Comment: 50+ clicks. Could not reprocude it. Using FF browser.

Comment: I get the described behavior in Chrome 26

Comment: Have you tried Chrome or Opera? It's most frequent in Opera, then Chrome, works fine in Firefox through... Is the CSS okay? Maybe it's some kind of browser bug then?

Comment: I'm seeing it in Chrome. About 1/20.

Comment: It's a problem with the button adding margins on active state. Basically, when the element moves, sometimes the click doesn't register. http://jsfiddle.net/4nz4v/1/

Comment: Exactly what I found, @AlfredXing.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. But is there any easy fix that will resolve it? Also, isn't it odd that it happens even when the cursor is exactly in the middle of clicked button?

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected it does seem to be a margin problem.

```
.button:active {
    margin: 4px 0 0 0;
}
```

Removing the above code resolves the issue. I would remove this code and add padding to it's parent for more consistant results.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how to do it, please? What if my buttons have no parents, only the body itself?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: use `mouseup` or `mousedown` instead of `click`:

```
$('.button').mouseup(function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4nz4v/3/

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately it won't help me, because the JS was only for demonstration.

Comment: @Wordpressor So in the real problem it's just a link? Maybe use the JS code and manually create a new tab/window?

Comment: exactly, the real problem is just a link... I don't want / can't use any JS with it because it's in fact countless number of links.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. It is very consistent: you just have to find which row it is that's unclickable. Check your JSFiddle again, and find the row 2 or 3 pixels below the text. That's where you can't click it — at all. If you can't find it, move your cursor from the bottom of the button to the top, slowly, one pixel at a time, clicking at each pixel.

The unclickable area is consistent horizontally; the whole pixel row is unclickable. I've found at max two unclickable pixel rows per button, if both a top and a bottom padding is modified.

The bug seems to occur when the padding/margin/border of the button or link is modified on the `:active` state.

This should be reported, along with your JSFiddle, here:

- https://bugs.webkit.org/enter_bug.cgi
- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list -> 'New issue'.